# Как в golang подключить другой файл?

Tags: golang, golang-faq

Как в golang подключить другой файл?

Я начал только экспериментировать с ним и пока пишу в одном файле.

Хотелось бы часть кода перенести в другой и подключить его к `main.go`

Comment: `import mylib`. Вам не помешает прочитать для начала [How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html) - вы же не хотите учить новый язык программирования на форумах?

Comment: Спасибо. Как Вы подсказали- сразу начал копать в нужном направлении. Здесь есть ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049903/how-to-use-custom-packages-in-golang   Причём работает,если разместить файл в папке и написать в main.go import "./file_1" если же без ./ и файл там-же...чего-то не работает. Ну и ладно. Смысл понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Import declarations — объявления импорта

выдержка из [документации](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations).

> An import declaration states that the source file containing the declaration depends on functionality of the imported package (§Program initialization and execution) and enables access to exported identifiers of that package. The import names an identifier (PackageName) to be used for access and an ImportPath that specifies the package to be imported.

мой вольный перевод:

> объявление импорта (*import*) гласит, что файл, содержащий это объявление, зависит от функциональности импортируемого пакета (см. §Program initialization and execution), и позволяет получить доступ к экспортируемым пакетом идентификаторам. объявление назначает идентификатор (PackageName) для доступа, а также ImportPath, который точно определяет местоположение импортируемого пакета.

примеры:

```
Import declaration          Local name of Sin

import   "lib/math"         math.Sin
import m "lib/math"         m.Sin
import . "lib/math"         Sin

import _ "lib/math"
```

Answer (score 1):

Не подключай и всё! Просто обращайтесь к классам и функциям в нём расположенным и всё.

В самом начале действительно возникают проблемы разбиения кода на файлы и выделение своих самостоятельных модулей.

1. Подключать через import файл go расположенный в той-же директории что и главный НЕ НУЖНО.
2. Осторожней со слешами ))) должны быть обратные \ я как-то брал путь из far ну и имел проблемы...